# ツールチップで表示される値に桁区切りのカンマを入れたい

Tags: highcharts

グラフにカーソルをあてた時に表示されるツールチップについて
表示される数値をカンマ区切りの値で表示する方法を教えて下さい。
30000　→　30,000

Comment: 先の質問に続き、回答いただき有難うございます。

Answer (score 2):

`Highcharts.setOptions`で`lang.thousandsSep`を設定してください。また、`tooltip.pointFormat`で書式の指定が必要です。
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.thousandsSep

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        decimalPoint: '.',
        thousandsSep: ','
    }
});

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: "Value: {point.y:,.1f} mm"
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1029.9, 1071.5, 1106.4, 1129.2, 1144.0, 1176.0, 1135.6, 1148.5, 1216.4, 1194.1, 1095.6, 1054.4]
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```